# PHP page returning 500 error and not displaying errors

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to make an aJax call to display a ticket and its replies, the aJax call works but the PHP page doesn't, it gives me a 500 error and I really don't know what is wrong with it, it is not even reporting any errors...

This is the code

```
<?php
include('../connect.php');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time;
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

}

if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])){
    $tID = $_POST['id'];

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT ID, Author, Message, AuthorID, cTime FROM Tickets WHERE ID = :tid LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bindParam(':tid', $tID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $auth = $result['Author'];
    $msg = $result['Message'];
    $authID = $result['AuthorID'];
    $tTime = humanTiming($result['cTime']);
    $stmt = null;

    echo $msg;
    echo '<hr />';
    echo '<p class="align-right">- by ' . $auth . ', ' . $tTime . ' ago.';
    echo '<br /> <br />';

    $crg = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM TicketReplies WHERE TicketID = :tid');
    $crg->bindParam(':tid', $tID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crg->execute();
    $count = $crg->rowCount();

    if($count != 0){
        echo '<h3><u>Replies</u></h3>';
        while($row = $crg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo '<div class="alert bg-grey">';
            echo '<span class="pull-left">by ' . $row['ReplyBy'] . ' - ' . humanTiming($row['cTime']) . ' ago';
            if($row['sMember'] != 0){
                echo '<span class="label bg-green pull-right">Staff Member</span>';
            }
            echo '<hr />';
            echo $row['ReplyMsg'];
            echo '<hr />';
            echo '<br/>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo '<p align="center">There are no replies.</p>';
    }


}


?>
```

Comment: did you try to var_dump something on that?

Comment: What is strange is that even after I commented everything and added echo 'hi'; I still get a 500 error

Comment: add `echo "Test"; exit;` before your include statement. See if you're able to get "Test", then check your connect.php file.

Comment: i guess you're editing the wrong script . re open your editor

Comment: Also share ajax code?

Comment: what your `connect.php` contains and check any syntax error

Comment: Oh my god... @TheGinxx009 lol, I was editing the right one but I was uploading it in the wrong folder... sorry guys..

Comment: hahahahaha i've been there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i guess you're editing the wrong script . re open your editor

Please mark this as right :) thank you. haha